# Flutter Driver waitFor/tap timed out

Tags: flutter, timeout, flutterdriver

I am trying to setup flutter driver on my project. I already did work with it in another project and didn't had these problems. I initialised flutter_driver in the dev_dependencies, and put an app.dart and app_test.dart under test_driver folder.
I initalized app.dart to have a running app with flutter driver and started to write my first tests. Strangely I am getting super weird errors, when i try to interact with certain widgets. A simple driver.waitFor or driver.tap gives me a timeout.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  group('App', () {
    late FlutterDriver driver;

    // Connect to the Flutter driver
    setUpAll(() async {
      // Connect to a running Flutter application instance.
      driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
    });

    tearDownAll(() async {
      await driver.close();
    });

    test('should check driver health status', () async {
      final health = await driver.checkHealth();
      expect(health.status, HealthStatus.ok);
    });

    Future waitForObject(
      SerializableFinder object,
      Duration timeout, {
      String errorMessage = "waitForObject timed out",
    }) async {
      final message = "ERROR ==> $errorMessage";
      return driver.waitFor(object, timeout: timeout).catchError((e) {
        throw message;
      });
    }

    test(
      'should tap on getting started button',
      () async {
        final gettingStartedButton = find.byValueKey('GETTING_STARTED');

        // Give the app some time to load
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

        print(
          await waitForObject(
            gettingStartedButton,
            const Duration(seconds: 5),
          ),
        );

        // final widgetTree = await driver.getRenderTree();
        // print(widgetTree.tree);

        // await driver.runUnsynchronized(() async {
        //   await driver.waitFor(gettingStartedButton);
        // });

        await driver.waitFor(gettingStartedButton);

        await driver.tap(gettingStartedButton);
      },
      timeout: Timeout.none,
    );
  });
}
```

flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart

error messages i logged:

- ERROR ==> waitForObject timed out
- VMServiceFlutterDriver: waitFor message is taking a long time to complete

The app is starting and i also logged the widget tree and the elements are in the visible spot. Health status of flutter driver is ok as well. I also tried driver.runUnsynchronized, but nothing seems to work.

I also tried to set Timeout.none, but that didn't help: [flutter-driver timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726510/flutter-driver-test-timeout)

Any ideas?